# Java Swing - Text and buttons not showing up

Tags: java, swing

Trying everything, just not showing up:

```
package me.ultimate.ST;

import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ST extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ST() {
        setSize(500, 600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setUndecorated(true);
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Test");
        label.setText("Some Test!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ST ex = new ST();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I then just get a black box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the label to the frame:

```
label.setText("Some Test!");
add(label);
```

I suggest you read the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for the basics. Maybe the section on `How to Use Labels` would be a good place to start. The tutorial will also show you a better way to design your class wo that you follow Swing guidelines.

Comment: A bit of a java expert, so I figured I could pick it up easily. I was a bit wrong :p thanks

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to add the label to the frame :)

```
add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Whatever layout you wish to use...

Comment: Thank you, I figured there had to be some method to add it.